# Why does the ngDialog div block expand to full-width when removing the CSS width parameter?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using ngDialog in AngularJS to create pop-up dialogs in my webapp.  ngDialog provides CSS that contains a width parameter.  If I override the paramater with `width: initial`, the block expands to be full-width.  I would expect (and desire) it to take up the minimum size necessary to show its contents.

Here is a [minimally working ngDialog exmaple on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4745/embedded/result/).  Click on the text to open the dialog and see it expand to full-width.

How can I adjust the css so that the div is just large enough to fit its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becuase the css by default is:

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-theme-plain .ngdialog-content {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 450px;
 }
```

If you override the `width: 450px`, then as a `div` - a block level element - it defaults to full width.

You can change it to `display: inline-block` to make it "just fit"

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  I use `display: inline-block` and `float` with `.clearfix` so much I mistook their behavior for the standard `block` behavior.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use css property display

```
display:table;
```

if you just want to show html table in `ngDialog`, this will work perfectly and will fit your table into it.

> Make sure your table width!

Comment: one liners can not be considered as answers..!!

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle, .ngDialog is attached to a div and doesn't overwrite it's CSS `display: block;` property, which is why box spans across the entire screen; it has nothing to do with the width property. Set .ngDialog to include `display: inline-block;` and remove any properties for width.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the ngDialog theme as below:

```
ngDialog.open({
                template: 'externalTemplate.html',
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-mine,
                scope: $scope
            });
```

I copyed the "ngdialog-theme-default" block from ngDialog-theme-default.css to mine.css, then change "width" and rename it to "ngdialog-theme-mine".

It works.

Comment: i wanted to include (modal) html element in same page rather then creating external html file (externalTemplate.html'). any suggestion !